# R Studio running scripts improperly?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm having a really strange issue with R Studio, where it's reading scripts improperly, but only for one project of mine. It looks like the actual command is getting garbled between the script and the console.

I run from the script something as simple as:

```
    library("ggplot2")
    library("plyr")
```

What I get is..

```
    > library("plyr")2")
    "rror: unexpected input in "library("ggplot2")
    >
```

The "E" in error is getting chopped off and it looks like the "2" from "ggplot2" is getting added to the "plyr" somehow. Anything from my script does this, and I had to run the script one line at a time. It's almost like highlighted text isn't getting read properly. When I run it one line at a time, it reads just fine.

This only happens with one project, and after having to force-quit it yesterday. I'm sure the problem is due to that, but it seems like something the program should be able to recover from. In the meantime I'm just going to save my workspace and scripts and create a new RStudio project, but that's a workaround rather than a solution.

Any thoughts? Has anyone else had this happen? Is this worthy of a bug report?

Edit/Update: I tried to create a new project in the same folder, and that didn't work since it tried to reload the old workspace. I deleted the project file itself along with all the hidden files, and it seems to be behaving OK so far.

Comment: looks like you have a stray `"` or `'` somewhere. Also, you do not need quotes in a `library` call, just `library(ggplot2)` is sufficient